# List all .jar files in a directory.sorted by modification date in python

Tags: python

for eg:

```
import  os, datetime

def get_path_list(arg):
app_list = []
for file in os.listdir(arg):
    if '.jar' in file:
        app_list.append(file)
print app_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
     arg = '/home/xyz/test'
     get_path_list(arg)
```

This is python code to find all jar file in test directory but how to sort all jar file based on modification datetime.

Comment: Instead of `if '.jar' in file:` you should do `file.endswith(".jar"):`

Answer (score 2):

First of all for checking the format of your file you can not use `in` operand you can use `endswith` or `fnmatch` and then sort the file list with [`os.stat().st_ctime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result.st_ctime):

```
import  os, datetime
from fnmatch import fnmatch

def get_path_list(arg):
app_list = []
for file in os.listdir(arg):
    if fnmatch(file,'*.jar'):
        app_list.append(file)
print sorted(app_list,key=lambda f:os.stat(f).st_ctime)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html), which use the `os.listdir()` and `fnmatch.fnmatch()` functions in concert.

```
 $ ll -lrt *jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 work work 0 Aug 27 18:17 a.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 work work 0 Aug 27 18:18 b.jar
-rw-rw-r--  1 work work 0 Aug 27 18:18 a1.jar

>>> import os, glob, time
>>> files = glob.glob("*.jar")
>>> sorted(files,key=lambda file:time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file)))
['a.jar', 'b.jar', 'a1.jar']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use *os.path.getmtime()* to get the latest modified time of a file. If you combine this with the list function *sort*, you can specify the key to sort on. By sending a lambda function as key, we specify the key to be the last modified time. The *os.path.join(arg, x)* is to get the full path to the file, where *arg* is your path argument, and *x* is the current file.

```
import  os, datetime

def get_path_list(arg):
    app_list = []
    for file in os.listdir(arg):
        if '.jar' in file:
            app_list.append(file)

    app_list.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(arg, x)))

    print app_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    arg = '/home/xyz/test
```